# How do I parse a JSON that has {} around each node in the array?

Tags: arrays, json, javascriptserializer

How do I parse a JSON like this with JavaScriptSerializer?

```
{
  "name": "value1",
  "age": "value2",
  "children": [{
    "child": { "name": "value1", "age": "value2" }
  }, {
    "child": { "name": "value1", "age": "value2" }
  }]
}
```

It's weird because the each child has a `{}` around it.
Edit: correcting a syntax mistake.

Comment: What is *weird* on this object?

Comment: so from my understanding normal JSON array should be like this

children: [
               "child": {"name": "value1", "age": "value2"},
               "child": {"name": "value1", "age": "value2"} 
              ]

Comment: **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. Emphasis on the word _"object"_.

Comment: @JimmyVo — That wouldn't be normal, that would be invalid and throw errors when you tried to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

`children` is an array of objects containing an object named `child`.

This JSON is valid, but I agree it can be simpler e.g:

```
{
   "name": "value1",
   "age": "value2",
   "children": [
      {"name": "value1", "age": "value2"},
      {"name": "value1", "age": "value2"}
   ]
}
```

---

In its current form, you can reach the first `name` with:

```
yourObjectName.children[0].child.name
```

With the one I suggest, it may be:

```
yourObjectName.children[0].name
```

*Note that your JSON is not valid, `children` should be between quotes (`"children"`).*